# TWRP unable to mount anything except external-sd (invalid argument)

Tags: rooting, twrp, 8.1-oreo

I'm trying to install Magisk on my Leagoo T8s but there's errors even before Magisk installation:

```
E:Primary block device '/dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/userdata' for mount point '/data' is not present!
Failed to mount '/data' (invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/cache' (invalid argument)
Failed to mount '/system' (invalid argument)
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Start by taking a deeper look into whats happening through an elevated privileged adb shell with this command: `adb shell`  then elevate privileges with `su` last post the out put from `e2fsck /dev/block/platform/bootdevice/by-name/userdata`

Comment: I don't have su, my phone isn't rooted...

Comment: That is one of the fantastic things about TWRP. It runs its shell with elevated privileges. It might fix the partition but at least it might return some useful information. If its easier the get thr `/cache/recovery/last_log` that will most likely have some helpful information. A snippet of escalating the adbd daemon to root: Always start adbd on userdebug and eng builds on property:ro.debuggable=1 #write /sys/class/android_usb/android0/enable 1 #start adbd setprop service.adb.root 1 # Restart adbd so it can run as root on property:service.adb.root=1 write